# jekyll 3.0.1 | Error: Liquid syntax error: Unknown tag 'endunless'

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm converting a needlessly PHP-based site to Jekyll. I've been factoring the PHP code out of the main template and replacing it with Liquid tags.

The following code throws an error:

```
{% for script in extra_scripts %}
    {$ unless script.contains '/' %}{% assign script = "/media3/js/{{ script }}.js" %}{% endunless %}
    <script src='{{ script }}' type='text/javascript'></script>
{% endfor %}
```

The error I get is:

```
  Liquid Exception: Liquid syntax error: Unknown tag 'endunless' in _layouts/template.html
jekyll 3.0.1 | Error:  Liquid syntax error: Unknown tag 'endunless
```

I can't find anything wrong with this code. Can someone else?

PS: I'm irked that Jekyll/Liquid can't be bothered to give a line number in their error messages. The only way I was able to find the offending code was by iteratively deleting code until the error went away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your `unless` tag.

```
{$ unless script.contains '/' %}
```

must be replaced by:

```
{% unless script contains '/' %}
```

Comment: Thanks. I found it about the same time as you posted. But, I edited the fix into your answer, as yours was as buggy as mine. This error is so easy to make!